# How do you guarantee that an incoming Excel file is from your original data source and not a fake?

Tags: excel, key, unique, uniqueidentifier

I have a series of Excel files that I send out to customers. They fill them out and send them back with their info. How do I ensure that the excel files coming back in are the same ones I sent out and don't just share the same title and rows/column names?

The data could be falsified with the same title, row/columns. I ideally need some kind of fingerprint, artifact, or key attached to each excel file that ensures it came from my original data source.

Comment: Then I think Excel is probably the wrong tool for you.  If security is that important on this document, you will probably need to create your own UI with a database back end with correct security claims to not allow the changing of data that is not supposed to change.

Comment: We used to send out data. But as everybody would get the same data for a given ID then if they wanted to alter it they could. BUT, our source was READ-ONLY so anyone else could get the original and the differences would be seen. Had a **big** argument with a senior manager when he ws p*ssed that he could not hide certain data "But it's **my** data" was one cry. My boss set him straight :)

Comment: @ScottCraner thanks, unfortunately this is not an option, client is locked into excel only. There must be a way to attach a key or artifact to excel I'd imagine.

Comment: Please don't insert "EDIT"s/"UPDATE"s, just make your post the best presentation as of edit time.  Please delete (your) & flag (others') obsolete comments. [Help] Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is along the lines of @SolarMike comment of keeping a read only version to which you compare when you get it back to make sure they did not change anything they were not supposed to.  Excel is open format.  It is nearly impossible to secure anything in Excel, anyone who can google can find ways around any security added to a workbook through normal means of Excel.

Comment: @ScottCraner in an excel file if you go into the info tab then select properties then select advanced properties a window pops up. Can't we embed some kind of data in there?

Comment: Sure, but I can copy the workbook, then change what I want to change and send it back.  I will still have damaged your data but that information will remain.

Comment: @ScottCraner right, but still kind of hidden - but yeah data could be tampered with still...

Comment: Yes, it basically comes down to whether you are trying to stop accidental or malicious threats.  There are ways around if one wants to be malicious.  If all you are concerned about is accidental than the answer below or the comments above would suffice.  Malicious, there is no guaranteed method.

Answer (score -1):

I used to add white characters to headings as one simple trick.

Or I would put in cells odd names combined with dates in rows way below or columns far to the right.

Even inserted a name using insert name. You can also define names with vba and sometimes delete does not completely remove them - used that to hide passwords...

Comment: Thanks but this isn't a workable solution for production software. Ideally I'd need a key of some kind or fingerprint or artifact attached to the excel files that uniquely identify they came from my data portal. Kind of like if someone wanted to counterfeit money where the watermark determines legitimacy.